# Why function(document) doesn't work in separate file?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file and this contain JavaScript code and works fine, but when I decided put the JS code in different file and call from the HTML file, doesn't work. Why?

The JS code is like this:

```
(function (document) {
    var toggleDocumentationMenu = function () {
        var navBtn = document.querySelector('.main-nav1');
        var navList = document.querySelector('.main-nav2');
        var navIsOpenedClass = 'nav-is-opened';
        var navListIsOpened = false;
        navBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!navListIsOpened) {
                addClass(navList, navIsOpenedClass);
                navListIsOpened = true;
            } else {
                removeClass(navList, navIsOpenedClass);
                navListIsOpened = false;
            }
        });
    };
    var toggleMainNav = function () {
        var documentationItem = document.querySelector('.main-nav3');
        var documentationLink = document.querySelector('.main-nav3 > .main-sub-nav');
        var documentationIsOpenedClass = 'subnav-is-opened';
        var documentationIsOpened = false;
        if (documentationLink) {
            documentationLink.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (!documentationIsOpened) {
                    documentationIsOpened = true;
                    addClass(documentationItem, documentationIsOpenedClass);
                } else {
                    documentationIsOpened = false;
                    removeClass(documentationItem, documentationIsOpenedClass);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    var isTouch = function () {
        return ('ontouchstart' in window) ||
            window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;
    };
    var addClass = function (element, className) {
        if (!element) {
            return;
        }
        element.className = element.className.replace(/\s+$/gi, '') + ' ' + className;
    };
    var removeClass = function (element, className) {
        if (!element) {
            return;
        }
        element.className = element.className.replace(className, '');
    };
    toggleDocumentationMenu();
    toggleMainNav();
})(document);
```

I read it's possible that works if I put like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // the javascript code here

});
```

But it still doesn't working.

Now I wonder, It's possible this code works fine in separate file?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"; are you seeing errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: When trying in a "separate file", how do you call it? Using <script> ? Please edit your question by showing what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script> in the Head section.

Comment: @TiesonT. When the code are into HTML file it works good, so I think it doesn't have errors. Just when I separate the JavaScrit code in other file (js.js), the HTML page doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @CesarNontol "I think it doesn't have errors" is proven or disproven by actually checking the console. Assuming you're on a Windows machine, you open the console by hitting your F12 key.

Comment: @TiesonT. You have the reason, I foud this ** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null js.js:9   ** toggleDocumentationMenu js.js:9   ** (anonymous function) js.js:58   ** (anonymous function) js.js:60